# OpenGL normals misunderstanding?

Tags: java, opengl, vertex, lighting, normals

I'm trying to get my lighting to work in OpenGL, using LWJGL as an implementation library. The problem I think I'm having, is that I don't set my normals properly and therefore the lighting doesn't work at certain angles. Here is the code for the cube I'm testing on:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);

glColor3f(r,g,b);

glNormal3f(position.x, position.y, position.z - radius - 0.1f);
glVertex3f(position.x + radius, position.y + radius, position.z - radius);
glVertex3f(position.x + radius, position.y - radius, position.z - radius);
glVertex3f(position.x - radius, position.y - radius, position.z - radius);
glVertex3f(position.x - radius, position.y + radius, position.z - radius);

glNormal3f(position.x, position.y, position.z + radius + 0.1f);
glVertex3f(position.x + radius, position.y + radius, position.z + radius);
glVertex3f(position.x + radius, position.y - radius, position.z + radius);
glVertex3f(position.x - radius, position.y - radius, position.z + radius);
glVertex3f(position.x - radius, position.y + radius, position.z + radius);

glNormal3f(position.x - radius - 0.1f, position.y, position.z);
glVertex3f(position.x - radius, position.y + radius, position.z + radius);
glVertex3f(position.x - radius, position.y - radius, position.z + radius);
glVertex3f(position.x - radius, position.y - radius, position.z - radius);
glVertex3f(position.x - radius, position.y + radius, position.z - radius);

glNormal3f(position.x + radius + 0.1f, position.y, position.z);
glVertex3f(position.x + radius, position.y + radius, position.z + radius);
glVertex3f(position.x + radius, position.y - radius, position.z + radius);
glVertex3f(position.x + radius, position.y - radius, position.z - radius);
glVertex3f(position.x + radius, position.y + radius, position.z - radius);

glNormal3f(position.x, position.y - radius - 0.1f, position.z);
glVertex3f(position.x + radius, position.y - radius, position.z + radius);
glVertex3f(position.x - radius, position.y - radius, position.z + radius);
glVertex3f(position.x - radius, position.y - radius, position.z - radius);
glVertex3f(position.x + radius, position.y - radius, position.z - radius);

glNormal3f(position.x, position.y + radius + 0.1f, position.z);
glVertex3f(position.x + radius, position.y + radius, position.z + radius);
glVertex3f(position.x - radius, position.y + radius, position.z + radius);
glVertex3f(position.x - radius, position.y + radius, position.z - radius);
glVertex3f(position.x + radius, position.y + radius, position.z - radius);

glEnd();
```

Comment: So... what is this *supposed* to do, and what is it actually doing?

Comment: I just want to make sure my normals are OK because I'm not I understand properly how to calculate them... it's a point in front of the surface ? right ?

Comment: @PhilippeParé: No, it's not a point in front of the surface, but the direction perpendicular to the surface, represented by a vector of length 1. You calculate them in R³ using the cross-product of the vectors spanning a triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal vectors are relative to the vertex itself and are always normalized (ie: they have length one).

So, a line like this:

```
glNormal3f(position.x, position.y, position.z - radius - 0.1f);
```

Should be replaced by:

```
glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```